# Firebase cloud function looping over and over with fetch()

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I'm working with Firebase functions for the first time. And I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I call my function 1 time, as seen in my network tab. But when I execute my http request to my cloud function It's looping over and over.

My function is intended to handle my contact form on my website and send the form with content to myself. I've tried to set a variable when the function has been called, but this is not working for me.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

How I call my function:

```
 sendEmail(url, {
  name: this.state.name,
  email: this.state.email,
  message: this.state.message,
  key: "env variable here"
}) {
    return fetch(url, {
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
      method: "POST",
      mode: "no-cors"
    }).then(response => response.json()); // parses response to JSON
   }
```

My FireBase cloudfunction:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const secureCompare = require("secure-compare");

const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: "myemail@gmail.com",
    pass: "mypw"
  }
});

exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(request.body);
  const key = data.key;
  let hasBeenCalled = false;

  // Exit if the keys don't match
  if (!secureCompare(key, functions.config().cron.key)) {
    console.log("The key provided in the request does not match the key set in the environment. Check that", key, "matches the cron.key attribute in `firebase env:get`");
    response
      .status(403)
      .send(
        'Security key does not match. Make sure your "key" URL query parameter matches the ' + "cron.key environment variable.");
    return null;
  }

 const emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
   const email = emailRegex.test(data.email) ? data.email : null;
   const mailOptions = {
     from: data.name + " <test@gmail.com>",
     to: "myemail@gmail.com",
     bcc: email,
     subject: "this is a message",
     text: data.message
   };


  if (!hasBeenCalled) {
    mailTransport
      .sendMail(mailOptions)
      .then(() => {
        this.hasBeenCalled = true;
        console.error("email sent to: " + mailOptions.to);
        console.error("email sent from: " + data.name);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.hasBeenCalled = true;
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically if your HTTPS-triggered function is being invoked multiple times, it means that you're not sending a response back. Sending a response is how the Cloud Functions environment knows that you're done, so it may assume something went wrong and retry:

```
exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(request.body);
  const key = data.key;
  let hasBeenCalled = false;

  // Exit if the keys don't match
  if (!secureCompare(key, functions.config().cron.key)) {
    console.log("The key provided in the request does not match the key set in the environment. Check that", key, "matches the cron.key attribute in `firebase env:get`");
    response
      .status(403)
      .send(
        'Security key does not match. Make sure your "key" URL query parameter matches the ' + "cron.key environment variable.");
    return null;
  }

 const emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
   const email = emailRegex.test(data.email) ? data.email : null;
   const mailOptions = {
     from: data.name + " <test@gmail.com>",
     to: "myemail@gmail.com",
     bcc: email,
     subject: "this is a message",
     text: data.message
   };


  if (!hasBeenCalled) {
    mailTransport
      .sendMail(mailOptions)
      .then(() => {
        this.hasBeenCalled = true;
        console.log("email sent to: " + mailOptions.to);
        console.log("email sent from: " + data.name);
        response.status(200).send("Mail sent");
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        this.hasBeenCalled = true;
        response.status(500).send(error);
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, this makes sense!